# To fetch all values even duplicated values only once

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web application of movies which has crew and casts . crew member can have more than one role in one movie and i want to fetch all movies that he participated in by using that roles table , so how do i select duplicated movies only once?

```
SELECT * FROM roles,movies WHERE roles.person = '$fullname' AND roles.movie = movies.title
```

Comment: You can simply use `DISTINCT`. If you need some values like the number of roles he participated per movie, you will need use `GROUP BY` and `AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS`

Comment: Can you add the full structure of the two tables?

Comment: Use the [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword. I have a funny feeling that your query is vulnerable to injection attack; you should look into using [MySQLi prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) depending on which you are using..